# Greenwich Mean Time to Indian Standard Time

Tags: perl

How to convert given Greenwich Mean Time to Indian Standard Time in perl?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It helps to know what format your desired input/output are, but:

```
use DateTime;
$datetime = DateTime->new( year => 2010, month => 12, day => 27, hour => 15, minute => 45, second => 15, time_zone => 'GMT' );
$datetime->set_time_zone( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
print $datetime->ymd, ' ', $datetime->hms;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [DateTime::TimeZone](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone) module? I believe it's got some pretty easy-to-use methods for time-manipulation.